# Android Show and hide views in AsyncTask

Tags: android, layout, android-asynctask

Hi I have a AysncTask that i'm wanting to inflate a loading view whilst that runs when it's finished hide it. does anyone know how to do this? at moment its not showing the loading view.

this is what i have tried

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadingView = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.loadingcell,
            null);

    //Check Preferences which sets UI

    checkPreferences();
   PostTask posttask;
   posttask = new PostTask();
   posttask.execute();

}




    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        boolean result = false;


        loadFixtures();
        publishProgress("progress");
        loadResultsFeed();
        publishProgress("progress");
        loadNewsFeed();
        publishProgress("progress");
        return result;
    }


    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i < progress.length; i++) {
                str.append(progress[i] + " ");



            }
    }

        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.v("BGThread", "begin fillin data");
         FillData();
         loadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
}
```

loadingcell.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white" 
    android:id="@+id/loadingcell">


    <include
        layout="@layout/header" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="87dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: [See this](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-asynctask-example.html)

Comment: don't repeat ur Que..duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11013505/1289716

Comment: @SamirMangroliya hi Samir is there a way i can do this without using a dialogue box i just want a page that has a a text view that says loading and a spinner then on postexecute have it hide

Comment: First use ProgressDialog they have already loading view and loading as a textview.

Comment: @SamirMangroliya i dont want to use dialog though i want my own custom one thats like this http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/progress-wheel

Answer (score 1):

You are not using an AsyncTask in you code. Use something like this:

```
private class doSomething extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Inflate you view or do anything here before loading stuff
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        //loading stuff
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        //change your UI - like a progressbar
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        //Hide the progressbar
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a content for the `Activity` - which you can set using [`setContentView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29)